# sum of multiplication of cells in the same row but different column for pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[2,3,4]})
```

My data looks like this

```
Index   A   B
0       1   2
1       2   3
2       3   4
```

I would like to calculate the sum of multiplication between A and B in each row.
The expected result should be (1x2)+(2x3)+(3x4) = 2 + 6 + 12 = 20.
May I know the pythonic way to do this instead of looping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try multiple columns `A` and `B` and then use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[2,3,4]})
print df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4

print df['A'] * df['B']
0     2
1     6
2    12
dtype: int64

print (df['A'] * df['B']).sum()
20
```

Or use [`prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) for multiple all columns:

```
print df.prod(axis=1)
0     2
1     6
2    12
dtype: int64

print df.prod(axis=1).sum()
20
```

Thank you [ajcr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840458/sum-of-multiplication-of-cells-in-the-same-row-but-different-column-for-pandas-d#comment59347471_35840496) for comment:

> If you have just two columns, you can also use **df.A.dot(df.B)** for extra speed, but for three or more columns this is the way to do it!

Comment: If you have just *two* columns, you can also use `df.A.dot(df.B)` for extra speed, but for three or more columns this is the way to do it!

Comment: print ((df['A'] * df['B']).sum()) works, without bracket throws error.